# Scroll to flash message after a long form is submitted using jquery in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, flash

In my rails app, i have a long form with ajax.I have flash message span after the form submission for both success and error of the form submission.As this is a large form so the message is hiding i need to manually scroll to the top to see the message.My form is bellow:

```
   <div class="address-form dropdown-form">
          <%= form_for(@user, :url => edit_info_user_path, method: 'POST', remote:true, :html => {:id => "edit-address"}) do |f| %>
            <%= hidden_field_tag "section","address-form" %>
            <span class="message"></span>

            <div class="registerbox">
              <fieldset class="address-fieldset">
                <legend>Your address:</legend>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :address1, '<span class="red">*</span> Address 1:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :address1, :required => true, :class => "input-xlarge" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :address2, 'Address 2:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :address2, :required => true, :class => "input-xlarge" %>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :city, '<span class="red">*</span> City:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :city, :required => true, :class => "input-xlarge" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :postcode, '<span class="red">*</span> Post Code:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.text_field :postcode, :required => true, :class => "input-xlarge" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <%= f.label :country, '<span class="red">*</span> Country:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <%= f.country_select :country, {:priority => %w(BD) }, {class: "span3 min-height-dropdown"} %>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="control-group">
                    <%= f.label :region, '<span class="red">*</span> Region / State:'.html_safe, :class => "control-label" %>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <%= render partial: 'users/subregion_select', locals: {parent_region: @user.country || "BD"} %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <%= f.hidden_field :step, :value => 3 %>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="loading-address"><%= image_tag('/assets/ajax-loader.gif') %></div>

                <%= f.submit "Update", :class => "btn btn-success" %>
              </div>

            <% end %>
          </div>
```

Now, i want to automatically scroll to the flash message after form submission.

But i don't have any idea how to accomplish this feature using jquery.

please help me.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add to Ajax onSuccess:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```